# Square root calculation in Scheme (SICP Exercise 1.7)

Tags: scheme, sicp, numerical-methods

I have done exercise 1.7 in SICP (calculate square root precision when change in guesses is under a certain value), but I am calling the change-in-precision function twice in each iteration, which disturbs me. I wonder if there is a better way to implement this.

```
(define (average . ns) (/ (apply + ns) (length ns)))

(define (change-in-precision guess x)
  ( - (- guess (average guess (/ x guess)))))

(define (sqrt guess x)
  (if (< (abs (change-in-precision guess x)) (/ 0.00000001 guess))
  (+ guess (change-in-precision guess x))
  (sqrt (+ guess (change-in-precision guess x)) x)))
```

Comment: Your edit was rolled back. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `change-in-precision`, you can avoid the negation by swapping the operands for the subtraction.

In `sqrt`, if the guess is already close enough, why not just return `guess`?

To eliminate the repeated call to `change-in-precision`, use a `let` to define a variable `delta`.

The two branches of the `if` should be indented.

Comment: `(/ 0.00000001 guess)` is not the same as `(/ guess 100000000)`; in the former, `guess` is in the denominator, whereas in the latter, `guess` is in the numerator. But `(/ 1 guess 100000000)` could work. Not sure if it's "more readable" at that stage, though.

Comment: @200_success Thank you for points 1,2 and 4. For point 3, I wanted to try and avoid a variable as we haven't done that in the book yet.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yes my way of doing it looks strange, but it helps me to think about what the precision implies.